# Is there any character limit in android textview?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to enter more than 2000 - 3000 characters in an android TextView

it does not display anything.

any one guide is there character limit on android textview or what ?

Comment: There is no character limit. It's hard to say what is going on without seeing your layout and how you are loading the text into the TextView, please add these additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some small testing in G3, I found that: 
If there is a TextView in the activtiy layout, it can show more than 4096 
characters, but when it owned by the item of listview, it just display 
invisible. So there's no hard limit, just what can be displayed depending on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Post your code might be your textview expand and fill the screen use Scrollview to handle this issue.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="0.75"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"
        android:textColor="@color/alert_dialog_heading_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_for_subheading" />
</ScrollView>
```