# Maximum line limits for Textview in android?

Tags: android

Maximum line limits for Textview in android ?

android:maxLines="?"

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: At the minimum, make it in the form of an actual question. Do you want to know what it does, why you would use it, or how you use it?

Answer (score 0):

from  [Is there any character limit in android textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060720/is-there-any-character-limit-in-android-textview)

I did some small testing in G3, I found that: If there is a TextView in the activtiy layout, it can show more than 4096 characters, but when it owned by the item of listview, it just display invisible. So there's no hard limit, just what can be displayed depending on the device